# How can I use a compressed connection between Django and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, django, compression, database-connection

I have compression on my MySQL server, and I'd like to ensure Django is making compressed connections. How can I do this?

Comment: Is this localhost connection or is the database in a different machine than the django server? There's no benefit of using compression for local connections which is the common confusion, at best you're just using up CPU cycles.

Comment: I know. Can you answer the question that was asked?

Answer (score 5):

Trial, error and inference suggest the solution is to use a `compress` field set to `True` in the `OPTIONS` dict:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'compress': True
        }        
    }
}
```

I can't confirm the connection is actually compressed though.

Answer (score 1):

A cursory (no pun intended) examinations of `/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py` of Django 1.3:

```
298     def _cursor(self):                                                          
299         if not self._valid_connection():                                        
300             kwargs = {                                                          
301                 'conv': django_conversions,                                     
302                 'charset': 'utf8',                                              
303                 'use_unicode': True,                                            
304             }                                                                   
305             settings_dict = self.settings_dict                                  
306             if settings_dict['USER']:                                           
307                 kwargs['user'] = settings_dict['USER']                          
308             if settings_dict['NAME']:                                           
309                 kwargs['db'] = settings_dict['NAME']                            
310             if settings_dict['PASSWORD']:                                       
311                 kwargs['passwd'] = settings_dict['PASSWORD']                    
312             if settings_dict['HOST'].startswith('/'):                           
313                 kwargs['unix_socket'] = settings_dict['HOST']                   
314             elif settings_dict['HOST']:                                         
315                 kwargs['host'] = settings_dict['HOST']                          
316             if settings_dict['PORT']:                                           
317                 kwargs['port'] = int(settings_dict['PORT'])                     
318             # We need the number of potentially affected rows after an          
319             # "UPDATE", not the number of changed rows.                         
320             kwargs['client_flag'] = CLIENT.FOUND_ROWS                           
321             kwargs.update(settings_dict['OPTIONS'])                             
322             self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)                        
323             self.connection.encoders[SafeUnicode] = self.connection.encoders[unicode]
324             self.connection.encoders[SafeString] = self.connection.encoders[str]
325             connection_created.send(sender=self.__class__, connection=self)     
326         cursor = CursorWrapper(self.connection.cursor())                        
327         return cursor
```

When creating a connection on line 322, the code does not seem to pass the [compress](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#functions-and-attributes) argument in kwargs, not by default anyway.

Passing `'compress': True` through `OPTIONS` should let you create a compressed connection when it's available, this dictionary is merged to kwargs on line 321.

There does not seem to be any other calls to the MySQLdb.connect() method in the rest of the backend. Note that MySQLdb is imported as: `import MySQLdb as Database` in that file.